# 相変わらずだよWhat is the meaning of this ending -azu in verbs

Tags: conjugations

Not long ago, I peeked into a slang book where I found the following expression:

> "あいかわらずだよ"

変わる　means to change but what happens in this case with the meaning? kawarazu
Thank you for your answer and help in advance.

Comment: I think the linked question should answer your question and more.